# ScrollView scroll responders interrupts Component's pan responder

Tags: react-native

I'm making a scrollable view containing a custom component with its PanResponder.

This is my main view:

```
<ScrollView>
    <CustomComponent />
    <CustomComponent />
    <CustomComponent />
</ScrollView>
```

And this is my CustomComponent:

```
<View>
    <Animated.View {...this.panResponder.panHandlers} style={panStyle1}>
        <Text>Sample text here</Text>
    </Animated.View>
</View>
```

Now, what happens is that when I try to drag and drop a CustomComponent (implemented via PanResponder), it stalls in between due to the Scrolling Responder Event. I found a solution to disable scroll during a PanResponderMove event: http://browniefed.com/blog/react-native-pan-responder-inside-of-a-scrollview/ but I don't know how to make it work.

I can only disable scroll in the main view, but my pan responder is in the child view (CustomComponent), how can I pass the information to parent view (main view) that pan responder is active, so that the ScrollView scroll event gets disabled?

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to add `onPanResponderTerminationRequest` in the `create` function, like this:

```
PanResponder.create({
  onPanResponderTerminationRequest: () => false,
  onPanResponderMove: ...
  ...
})
```